# API vs Angular web application templates in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have completed a tutorial where I created an API using .NET core:
[image]

and then creating a separate Angular project using Angular CLI that I edit in VSCode.

This all works fine but I was wondering how this is different from using the the Angular Template in VS studio:

[image]

I understand that this might get downvoted but all I have found on these is how-to tutorials. I would like to understand the pros and cons of each and perhaps where I would use one over the other. The Angular project in Visual Studio allows me to get user authentication right out of the box which is why I'm looking at it.

Just to be clear, I'm looking to understand the differences between

```
(1) .NET Core Web API + Angular CLI Project
(2) Angular Project Web Application
```

Comment: The only main advantages for me with `Angular` template is you don't need to deal with `CORS` since they will be the same origin. Offers the convenience of hosting both project types in a single app project. Consequently, the app project can be built and published as a single unit. If you have multiple clients consuming the API then it's most likely better separating them. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular project template is equivalent to creating an ASP.NET Core project to act as an API backend and an Angular CLI project to act as a UI. The template offers the convenience of hosting both project types in a single app project. Consequently, the app project can be built and published as a single unit. You can refer to below article :

[Use the Angular project template with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

The big difference is from  ASP.NET Core 3.0 or later , the template offers authentication in Single Page Apps (SPAs) using the support for API authorization. ASP.NET Core Identity for authenticating and storing users is combined with IdentityServer for implementing Open ID Connect:

[Authentication and authorization for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

In Visual Studio ,choose Angular template -->Change Authentication --> choose Individual User Accounts . Or you can use .NET Core CLI :`dotnet new angular -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual`

Comment: is there a way to easily split these projects later? I read small changes have been made in the default angular & asp.net core api project.

Comment: @KevinvanSchaijk I'm also interested in knowing what the patterns are for evolving (splitting) the combined architecture. I imagine you would separate the client from the backend into different repos and develop and deploy independently. The reasoning for split could be based on at least a couple of factors I guess: application size, team size...not sure what else.